# How to Add "total" column in bar charts in Power BI

Tags: charts, powerbi, bar-chart, powerquery

So I have sales numbers for two cities , Mumbai and Delhi which are on my X- axis as shown in the picture.

I want to be able to add a new column next to Mumbai and Delhi columns known as "Total" column, which holds the sales numbers for both the cities combined. I have posted the sample picture of how i want it to look below !

[image: Bar chart Power BI]

Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

Try with dax function, I think its possible.